# How Can I Make Preseed Work With PXE Netboot?

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, tftp, netinstall

I've been experimenting with PXE netboot with TFTP for the last few days and I have successfully setup everything except the preseed.  I can see that Ubuntu (versions 14.10-15.04, amd64 and i386) successfully pulls the preseed.cfg from my web server and loads it, but it still runs the interactive installer.  Here are my boot options:

```
LABEL 1
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)
    KERNEL Ubuntu/15.04/amd64/vmlinuz.efi
    APPEND auto=true quiet keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us preseed/locale=en_US hostname=us domain=valdeon.co kbd-chooser/method=us console-keymaps-at/keymap=us priority=critical only-ubiquity boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.1.1.1:/srv/install/Ubuntu/15.04/amd64 initrd=Ubuntu/15.04/amd64/initrd.lz url=http://10.1.1.1/pxe/Ubuntu/15.04/amd64/preseed.cfg
    TEXT HELP
    Boot the Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit DVD
    ENDTEXT
LABEL 2
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu 15.04 (32-bit)
    KERNEL Ubuntu/15.04/i386/vmlinuz
    APPEND boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.1.1.1:/srv/install/Ubuntu/15.04/i386 initrd=Ubuntu/15.04/i386/initrd.lz url=http://10.1.1.1/pxe/Ubuntu/15.04/i386/preseed.cfg
    TEXT HELP
    Boot the Ubuntu 15.04 32-bit DVD
    ENDTEXT
LABEL 3
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit)
    KERNEL Ubuntu/14.10/amd64/vmlinuz.efi
    APPEND boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.1.1.1:/srv/install/Ubuntu/14.10/amd64 initrd=Ubuntu/14.10/amd64/initrd.lz url=http://10.1.1.1/pxe/Ubuntu/14.10/amd64/preseed.cfg
    TEXT HELP
    Boot the Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit DVD
    ENDTEXT
LABEL 4
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu 14.10 (32-bit)
    KERNEL Ubuntu/14.10/i386/vmlinuz
    APPEND boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.1.1.1:/srv/install/Ubuntu/14.10/i386 initrd=Ubuntu/14.10/i386/initrd.lz url=http://10.1.1.1/pxe/Ubuntu/14.10/i386/preseed.cfg
    TEXT HELP
    Boot the Ubuntu 14.10 32-bit DVD
    ENDTEXT
```

The one that I'm trying to get working is the Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit).  I've been changing boot options that many say have fixed this problem but to no avail.

I don't want to paste my whole `preseed.cfg` here because I think it's a bit too long but I pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/0KRUvMcB

Does anyone have any ideas?